# Build a map using values of multiple objects in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, maps

I need to build a map "A" from an existing array of objects. However the key value pairs on Map A are from the values of existing Object keys "id" and "cap".

Is it possible to read the values of 2 keys  and store as an object

```
  var items =  [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Primary",
                "cap": [{
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "1s"
                    }, {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "T2s"
                    }]
                },{
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Secondary",
                "cap": [{
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "1s"
                    }, {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "T2s"
                    }
                ]
            }]
```

My map needs to be like this

```
          { "1" : [{
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "1s"
                    }, {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "T2s"
                    }],
              "2" : [{
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "1s"
                    }, {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "T2s"
                    }]
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array#reduce` to achieve the results like below:

```js
var items = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Primary",
  "cap": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "1s"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "T2s"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Secondary",
  "cap": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "1s"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "T2s"
  }]
}];

var ans = items.reduce(function(v, i) {
  v[i.id] = i.cap;
  return v;
}, {});

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a simple loop on the original array, and defining a new key: value pair into the object.

```
// Create the map
var map = {}
// For every 'item' within the 'items' array
items.forEach(item => {
    // Map the item ID to the item.cap array
    map[item.id] = item.cap
}
```

```js
var items = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Primary",
  "cap": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "1s"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "T2s"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Secondary",
  "cap": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "1s"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "T2s"
  }]
}]

var map = {}
items.forEach(item => {
  map[item.id] = item.cap
})

console.log(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method.

```js
 var items =  [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Primary",
                "cap": [{
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "1s"
                    }, {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "T2s"
                    }]
                },{
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Secondary",
                "cap": [{
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "1s"
                    }, {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "T2s"
                    }
                ]
            }];

var obj = {};
var res = Array.from(items, x => obj[x.id] = x.cap);

console.log(obj);
```